# Name for square sub-matrix containing no diagonals of main matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Using the matrix below for illustration, is there a term for the area(s) of the matrix which contains "B"? This would be the area of a matrix that is the largest possible square non-symmetircal submatrix that does not contain the diagonals of the main matrix.

$
\begin{pmatrix}
A & A & B & B \\
A & A & B & B \\
B^T & B^T & C & C \\
B^T & B^T & C & C
\end{pmatrix}
$

I ask because, in my field, these three areas of a matrix each have important distinctions, and it's useful to compare these submatrices. I'm putting together some documentation and want to make sure that I'm using the right terminology!

*Also, if there is a specific term for A and C, or for splitting a matrix into these four equal sized parts, then please go ahead and tell me.*

Comment: The A's form a "leading principal submatrix".  Not sure if there's common terminology for the rest.

Comment: Perhaps a trailing principal submatrix? A Google search returns some hits...

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me; haven't encountered the term myself

Comment: I'll maybe describe it as "the submatrix remaining once the leading and trailing principal submatrices are excluded (herein referred to as **B**)" and by coincidence, in my field the annotation for this part is also B!